# SQL Server Returning multiple values Using COUNT from different tables in single query

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have different tables in a SQL Server 2012 database, with the following structure:

- `userstbl` has the user full_name and ID --> this has the info of the dentist.
- `bookingtbl` has Id, patient_ID (related to another table has the info file of the patient), booking_date, InvoiceID (Related to another table Invoice).
- `servicetbl`: ID, service_id (related to another table that has the cost of the service), booking_ID.
- `invoicetbl`: ID, TotalCost.

What I want to get from my procedure is to return:

user_ID as DrD, Full_name as DrName, count of the bookings, count of Services, sum of total from invoices.

based on a given date.

I tried the following but smthn is still missing:

```
create Proc SelectDrWork(@date Date)
as
begin
    select 
        userstbl.[user_id],userstbl.full_name,
        count(bookingtbl.bookingID), 
        count(servicetbl.serviceID),
        sum(invoice.Total)
    from 
        userstbl, bookingtbl, Servicetbl, invoice
    where 
        userstbl.IsActivated = 'True' 
        and userstbl.description = 'Dr'
        and bookingtbl.dr_id = [user_id] 
        and cast(bookingtbl.[date] as date) = cast(@date as date)
        and servicetbl.booking_id = book_number 
        and invoice.inv_id = bookingtbl.invoiceID 
    group by 
        [user_id], book_number, diaganosis_serv_id
end
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the advice. I am still new in the field, and I'm trying to improve my skills.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. Very Simple:

```
ALTER Proc SelectDrWork(@date Date)
as
begin
select userstbl.[user_id],userstbl.full_name,count(distinct book_number) as BookingCount,count(service_id)as ServiceCount,sum(invoice.Total) as Total
from userstbl, bookingtbl, diaganosistbl, invoice
where userstbl.IsActivated='True' and userstbl.description='Dr'
and bookingtbl.dr_id=[user_id] 
and cast(bookingtbl.[date] as date)= cast(@date as date)
and diaganosistbl.booking_id=book_number 
and invoice.inv_id=bookingtbl.invoiceID 
group by [user_id],full_name
end
```